# Why react-testing-library is showing reference error

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm trying to run a simple test using react-testing-library, this under a react project without create-react-app (CRA) I have a basic webpack config and don't know if I need to setup anything else.

Here is the test

```
import React from "react";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import { prettyDOM } from "@testing-library/dom";
import Button from "./Button";

test("renders content", () => {
  const props = {
    text: "Test",
    size: "lg",
    color: "black",
    type: "submit",
    buttonClass: "button-oaauth-signup",
    fullWidth: true,
  };

  const component = render(<Button {...props} />);

  component.getByText("Test");
});
```

Here is my ***package.json***

```
{
  "name": "firmavirtual",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack --mode=development",
    "build": "webpack --mode=production",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.8",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.8",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
    "@svgr/webpack": "^5.5.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.15.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "babel-jest": "^27.3.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.3",
    "css-loader": "^6.5.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "jest": "^27.3.1",
    "node-sass": "^6.0.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "^17.0.2",
    "sass-loader": "^12.2.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "svg-url-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "webpack": "^5.60.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.3.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.5.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.3.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.0.5",
    "@mui/material": "^5.0.6",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-google-login": "^5.2.2",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.18.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0"
  }
}
```

Here is my ***webpack.config.js***

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".json", ".jsx", ".scss", ".svg", ".png", ".jpg"],
    modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, "src"), "node_modules"],
  },
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js",
    path: path.join(__dirname, "public"),
  },
  plugins: [new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin({})],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules|bower_components/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        options: {
          presets: ["@babel/env", "@babel/preset-react"],
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: ["@svgr/webpack"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "file-loader",
            options: {
              name: "[name].[ext]",
              outputPath: "assets/fonts/",
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  devtool: "eval-cheap-module-source-map",
  devServer: {
    static: path.join(__dirname, "public"),
    port: 5000,
  },
};
```

Running ***npm run test*** show this error

```
> firmavirtual@1.0.0 test
> jest

 FAIL  src/components/buttons/Button.test.js
  ✕ renders content (2 ms)

  ● renders content

    The error below may be caused by using the wrong test environment, see https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testenvironment-string.
    Consider using the "jsdom" test environment.
    
    ReferenceError: document is not defined

      15 |   };
      16 |
    > 17 |   const component = render(<Button {...props} />);
         |                     ^
      18 |
      19 |   component.getByText("Inicio con Google");
      20 | });

      at render (node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/pure.js:83:5)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/buttons/Button.test.js:17:21)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        5.179 s
Ran all test suites.
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried the suggested solution in the error? " The error below may be caused by using the wrong test environment..."

Comment: @JakeWorth well I guess I needed to search a little more, in jest.config.js I added testEnvironment: "jsdom" and that solved the problem. Silly me

Answer (score 2):

Well I guess I needed to search a little more

In ***jest.config.js*** add

```
module.exports = {
  // Add the correct environment
  testEnvironment: "jsdom",
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$":
      "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
    "\\.(css|less)$": "identity-obj-proxy",
  },
};
```

That solved the problem. Silly me